# Correct way to convert interest rates

Tags: finance

Let's assume $r_{360,sa}$ is a zero coupon rate compounded **semi-annually**, under **act/360** day count. I'd like to convert it to zero coupon rate compounded **annually**, under **act/365**. Is the below conversion correct?

$$r_{365,a}=\Big(1+\frac{r_{360,sa}\cdot365}{2\cdot360}\Big)^2-1$$

I found it in many textbooks. Nevertheless, some people claim that I should use

$$1+r_{365,a}=\Big(1+\frac{r_{360,sa}}{2}\Big)^{2\cdot \frac{365}{360}}$$

to get $r_{365,a}$. I'm kind of confused now...

Answer (score 1):

Note that your second formula is equivalent to
$$
r_{365,a}=
\left(\left(1+\frac{r_{360,sa}}{2}\right)^{365/360}\right)^2 - 1
$$

So the only disagreement between the two formulas is that
$$
\left(1+\frac{365}{360}\cdot\frac{r_{360,sa}}{2}\right) \neq
\left(1+\frac{r_{360,sa}}{2}\right)^{365/360}
$$

For small values of $r_{360,sa}$ these formulas are approximately equal.
Compounding over many years will magnify the discrepancy.

The second formula appears to be a slightly better predictor
of the value of the $180$-day compounding over the course of
very many years; for example, over the course of $180$ periods of $365$ days
there will be $365$ compounding periods of $180$ days each, 
which agrees with the fact that the second formula predicts a value of 
$\left(1+\frac{r_{360,sa}}{2}\right)^{365}$ over that period of time.

The first formula appears to be a lot easier to calculate using
pencil and paper or the kinds of electronic (or even mechanical)
calculators that were in common
use in years past (before practically everyone had an $x^y$ key).
Moreover, unless you have an extremely high rate or a very long
time period, the discrepancy with the second formula will be a
tiny fraction of a percent of the balance.
Perhaps that explains why it became so popular.

Comment: Thanks David. So there is no one correct formula?

Comment: If "correct" means "mathematically equal under all circumstances" I don't think you _can_ have a "correct" formula, due to the different periods of compounding. I'd probably use the second formula since nowadays it is not really harder to compute.